# Laravel append data to $cList after ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I dont know how to append new data from controller to the html view.

my ajax post (it works):

```
   $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: "json",
    url:getWizardSelectionUri,
    data: ....
    success:function(data){ 
        $('#bikeliste').empty()
         .....
```

here is my html with the static request

```
 @foreach(App\Bike::all() as $cList)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <table border="0" width="100%">
          <colgroup width="200" span="3"></colgroup>
            <td>   
                <a href="{{$cList->link}}" target="_blank">

                    <img src="{{$cList->bildlink}}" height="150" width= "auto"> 
                </a>
                <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h5>
                    <a href="{{$cList->link}}" target="_blank">
                        <strong>{{$cList->hersteller}} </strong>
                        {{$cList->modell}} 
                        {{$cList->modelljahr}} 
                        <br>

                    </a>
                </h5>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($cList->gewicht)
                    <strong>Gewicht: </strong> {{$cList->gewicht}}<br>
                @endif
                @if ($cList->laufraddurchmesser)
                    <strong>Radgröße: </strong>{{$cList->laufraddurchmesser}}<br>
                @endif


            </td>
        </table>
        <br>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

is there a posibility to change the data without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data from your ajax to your Controller asynchronously, so in your controller method you just return a json response:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    ... your store function

    if($store) {
        return response()->json([
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $data
    ]);

}
```

`$data` contains the stuff your saved in your database you return that data to your ajax promise and get the data. So in your ajax success function you have to do something like this:

```
success:function(response){ 
    ...
    var data = response.data // holds the data
    yourhtml.append(data); // dissables this one ...
```

In your success you now holds the saved data and need your append that now into your html.

Comment: thanks for the reply. controller and ajax works. but is there a posibility to change the $cList values asynchronously, or do I have to append all data at the html at its place?

Comment: Well it is asynchronously, you are posting the data asynchronously to your server side controller -> your laravel controller store method there you return a json to your ajax promise and append the stored data to your html view, this is all done without a full page load, it is asynchronously:)